# sql count function returning object as output in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.1

I'm passing value from laravel model to blade, am getting `[object Object]` as output. I want number or array.

Model:

```
public static function count($data){
  $post_id = $data->a;  
  $count_value=DB::select('select count(*) as count FROM pp_like WHERE  post_id= ?', [$post_id]); 
  return (array)$count_value[0];
}
```

> blade-js:

```
res.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  alert(data);
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure what `data` argument represents. What you get if you replace `alert(data);` with `alert(JSON.stringify(data));`?

Comment: thaks bro its working.

Comment: If you find my help useful, consider upvoting and accepting my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your `data` argument is parsed JSON object. If you know the exactly name of the property you want to access, you can use `data.property` where `property` contains the value you are looking for. However, if you are not sure what `data` contains, you can replace `alert(data);` with `alert(JSON.stringify(data));` to see the properties of your object.

Answer (score 0):

change your query to

```
 $count =  DB::table('pp_like')->where('post_id','=',$post_id)->count();
 return $count;
```

now you will get number as result.